# How to get uninterpreted Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rack

I'm looking for a way to get the raw uninterpreted Rails route.

Say I have a route:

`/data_model/23455-cooltitle/sub_models`

When accessed I'd like to get the original route with parameters like:

`/data_model/:model_id/submodels`

Comment: For what purpose? This seems like a really weird request.

Comment: At a very high level. I have a 3rd party service that contains data that we want to map to specific sections of our rails app. We can tag the data in the 3rd party service with strings. Our rails app then retrieves the data with those strings. Using controller/action name is too general and doesn't always map 1-to-1 with our routes. I wanted to map the data with the original routes instead of interpreted routes to cover a whole section or routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what you want, but I'm going to assume you mean that given a `String` representing a path that maps onto one of our routes, you'd like to get back a `String` with the path segment parameters replaced by their identifying keys. You can do this as follows:

```
def uninterpret(path)
  path_params = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)
  path_params.each do |key, value|
    path.sub!(value, ":#{key}")
  end
  path
end
```

I'm sure there are some edge cases unaccounted for there, but that should work for your standard resourceful route.